# Can MPAndroidChart automatically convert units?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

If I have a `List` of entries in some unit (for example meters) that are being displayed in a [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/) `LineChart`, is there a way to easily change the unit that the values are being displayed in? Let's say I want to display them in kilometers instead, can MPAndroidChart do the conversion automatically, or do I have to manually create a new `List` of all the entries divided by 1000 and display that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`IAxisValueFormatter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface) interface to achieve this result. For example, assuming that the values are in meters (m) and you want to display labels in kilometers (km), something like this might work:

```
public class KilometerValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        float kilometers = value / 1000f;
        return kilometers + " km"; // maybe format to a specific number of decimals here
    }
}
```

Then set the `KilometerValueFormatter` to your axis using:

```
mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new KilometerValueFormatter());
```

**Note:** starting with version **`3.0.0`** of this library, the `AxisValueFormatter` interface has been renamed to `IAxisValueFormatter`!

Comment: Very sophisticated and well formatted answer, thank you!